# button.PerformClick(); not working in Form Load

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm calling a button click in the form_load like this:

```
public void Form1_Load(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    button.PerformClick();
}
```

But upon loading the button does not get clicked, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: PerformClick() can have side-effects due to validation which may prevent the event from running.  Best to not do this and just call your Click event handler directly.  Or it actually works but you just can't see it because the window isn't visible yet.  Your snippet sucks.

Comment: `button_Click(null, null);` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public void Form1_Load(object s, EventArgs e){
  button.PerformClick();
}
```

Looks like **you didn't register the Form1_Load** as event handler for the `Load` event of your form. Try this:

```
public Form1(){
   InitializeComponent();
   Load += Form1_Load;//Register the event handler so that it will work for you.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can write whatever you want to do inside of click in another function and call that from inside the click handler or programmatically like this -

```
public void Form1_Load(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        //button.PerformClick();
        PerformClickAction();
    }

void button_click(object sender,EventArgs e) 
{
    PerformClickAction();
}

void PerformClickAction()
{
    // Write what you need to do on click
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just call the handler:  `button_click(button, new EventArgs());`?

Comment: always good to keep it separated if you want to do it both programatically and as a handler ... button_click doesn't sound a very convincing and readable name when called from some other method...

Comment: Just for future visitors who choose to do what @DonBoitnott mentioned in his comment. It's always recommended to use `EventArgs.Empty` for any events or handlers that do not use a derived class. This prevents creating new objects and just uses a single instant for everything.
Example: `button_click(button, EventArgs.Empty);`

Answer (score 0):

To get the button clicked on form load, you need to fire an event after the form is loaded, try this

```
public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        //Event fired
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

}

//Event Handler 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```